# Profiles are not appearing in Quality profiles tab

Tags: sonarqube

I have configured SonarQube(4.5.1 version) in Windows7. And run it by clicking the StartSonar.bat file in windows-x86-64 folder(Because my system is 64 bit.). Then, I have opened browser and connected to server using url `http://localhost:9000`. And logged into the server As Admin. And navigated to "Quality profiles" tab. But, I didn't find any default profiles i.e,FindBugs and SonarWay. I have re installed the server to resolve it. But, It is not working. Can any one tell me what is the problem in Sonar which is configured in my machine.

Note: Same server installed in another machine. Profiles are showing in that machine.

Comment: Which plugins are installed? You can see them in the "Update Center" entry of the "Settings" administration space.

Comment: I have verified in "Update Center". No plugins are installed till now @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam

Comment: Not even the Java plugin? You have manually removed it? That would be a very good explanation of why you don't see any quality profile.

Comment: I didn't remove it. By default it showing no plugins. how to add it@Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam

Comment: Something is broken with your install then. Please reinstall from scratch following carefully the install guide.

Comment: Thank you @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam. I have reinstalled it. Now, It is working.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer so that you can accept it for other people to know that it was the solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is broken with your install. Please reinstall from scratch following carefully the install guide.